# Max/min of trained TensorFlow NN

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I would like to understand what the best way is to conduct further analysis on a trained TensorFlow neural network for regression.

Specifically, I am looking on how to find further maxima/minima from a trained neural network (equivalent to finding max/min from a regression curve). The easy way is to obviously "try out" all possible combinations and check the result set for a max/min, but testing all combinations can quickly become a huge resource sink when having multiple inputs and dependent variables.

Is there any way to use a trained TensorFlow neural network to conduct these further analyses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As networks are trained incrementally, you can find the maximum incrementally.

Suppose you have a neural network with an input size of 100 (e.g. a 10x10 image) and a scalar output of size 1 (e.g. the score of the image for a given task).
You can incrementally modify the input, starting from random noise, until you obtain a local maximum of the output. All you need is the gradients of the output with respect to the input:

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100], mean=127.5, stddev=127.5/2.))
output = model(input)

grads = tf.gradients(output, input)
learning_rate = 0.1
update_op = input.assign_add(learning_rate * grads)
```

Comment: Looks very promising, I didn't know one could so easily get the gradient  in TF. Just for my understanding: are you basically suggesting running another "GradientDescent" or "GradientAscent" on the trained network (until gradient = 0)?

Comment: Yes, but you only update manually the input, so all the weights of the network stay fixed. The convergence should be easier because there all less parameters.

Answer (score 1):

ANNs is not something which can be checked analytically. It has sometimes millions of weights and thousands of neurons, non-linear activation functions of different types, convolution and max-pooling layers.. No way you analytically determine anything about it. Actually that's why networks are trained incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was not asking if an analytical approach would be possible or not. My question was more about alternative, potentially algorithm based, solutions.

Comment: Got it. Well, than you can rely on Olivier's answer, I believe.